# Are neutrinos affected by gravity fields?

Tags: black-hole, neutrinos

Am asking if a neutrino can be pull by the gravity field of a quasar or a black hole, assuming the neutrino have momentum. It could be possible in the that a neutrino can orbit a black hole at an orbit equivalent to the Schwarzschild radius give or take. If it even possible for a neutrino to go through a black hole?

Comment: Your question is possibly answered at:
http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23899/are-neutrinos-affected-by-gravity or
http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/57681/do-neutrinos-of-any-flavor-get-trapped-in-black-holes

Comment: With respect to gravity, neutrinos should behave like other particles.

Comment: Also https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15263/neutrino-unaffected-by-gravity This seems a rather common question in SE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you buy into General Relativity (you need to throw out an awful lot of modern physics if you don't), gravity is a manifestation of the shape of spacetime around massive objects. It's not that they are being "pulled," but rather that they are just following the straightest path through spacetime that they can. Neutrinos would be the same as any other particles in that respect, and following anything other than this path would require some extraordinary gymnastics and external forces.